# Can I use NVIDIA-PRIME on a non-Ubuntu Debian system? If not, how do I use my NVIDIA card without Bumblebee?

Tags: debian, nvidia, optimus, deepin

I have Bumblebee installed but it has a number of problems, not the least of which is being unable to use Vulkan. I tried following the instructions [here](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers/Optimus), in addition to running `# apt remove bumblebee*`. I rebooted and was able to login with lightdm, but after that the display was black, so I reverted the changes using a different session not running X.

Is there something I should do not spelled out in that linked page? It seems like it was written for those trying to set up their NVIDIA-optimus stack, not modify it.

I'm running Deepin 15.4.1, which is based on Debian Sid, with slightly different package repositories.

Comment: If your GPU is compatible with the FOSS Nouveau drivers you can get rid of the non free Nvidia drivers and simply use the Linux kernel's built-in VGA Switcheroo tool as an alternative to Bumblebee. Have a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/568378) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Arch Linux uses AUR, a package management and delivery system maintained by
the arch linux user community, less strict than debian based package management. So I would consider Arch Linux or distros based on it.

Comment: I tried Manjaro and Antergos, but both failed to boot on my system after install. This was about 3 months ago, and I think I heard something about Manjaro improving UEFI support, so perhaps I'll try it again if I can't figure this out.